# Speed improvement using multiple threads

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have a CustomControl called PlaylistView. It displays elements in a playlist with name and thumbnail. The method DisplayPlaylist ensures that a thread is started, in which the individual elements are added one by one and the thumbnails (30th frame) are read out:

```
public void DisplayPlaylist(Playlist playlist)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(() => DisplayElements(playlist));
    thread.Start();
}

private void DisplayElements(Playlist playlist)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < playlist.elements.Count; i++)
        DisplayElement(playlist.elements[i], i);
}

private void DisplayElement(IPlayable element, int index)
{
    VideoSelect videoSelect = null;

    if (element is Audio)
        //
    else if (element is Video)
        videoSelect = new VideoSelect(index, element.name, GetThumbnail(element.path, SystemData.thumbnailFrame));

    videoSelect.Location = GetElementsPosition(index);

    panel_List.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => 
    {
        panel_List.Controls.Add(videoSelect);
    }));
}

private Bitmap GetThumbnail(string path, int frame)
{
    VideoFileReader reader = new VideoFileReader();
    try
    {
        reader.Open(path);

        for (int i = 1; i < frame; i++)
            reader.ReadVideoFrame();

        return reader.ReadVideoFrame();
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

But there is a problem.

It is much too slow (about 10 elements/sec). With a playlist length of 614, you would have to wait more than a minute until all are displayed. Each time you change the playlist, such as adding or deleting an item, the procedure starts with the new item. Adding 2 or more will make it even more complicated.

I now had the approach to use multiple threads and the number of threads used for this to be specified by the user (1 to max 10). The implementation in the code currently looks like this (only changed parts compared to the previously posted code)

```
public void DisplayPlaylist(Playlist playlist)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < SystemData.usedDisplayingThreads; i++)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(() => DisplayElements(playlist, i));
        thread.Start();
    }
}

private void DisplayElements(Playlist playlist, int startIndex)
{
    for (int i = startIndex; i < playlist.elements.Count; i += SystemData.usedDisplayingThreads)
        DisplayElement(playlist.elements[i], i);
}
```

The problem is that now very often `null` is returned by the GetThumbnail function, so an error occurs. In addition, a `System.AccessViolationException` is often thrown out.

In my opinion, the reason for this is the presence of multiple, simultaneously active VideoFileReaders. However, I do not know what exactly triggers the problem so I cannot present any solution. Maybe you know what the actual trigger is and how to fix the problem or maybe you also know other methods for speed improvement, which maybe even more elegant.

Comment: you have two choices: 1) introduce lock waits on the parallel video readers (slow) or 2) manually make 10 unrelated lists separately, run them in 10 threads in parallel and use `static bool flag` when each worker thread complete and `await` all ten bool flags

Comment: you can implement paging so list populates on demand.

Comment: @Amit you can but his question doesn't mention that he doesn't need them all, so I err'd on the side of assuming he knew what he was doing regarding that

Comment: @MrHeelis of course.. this is just a suggestion else it would be in answer section !

Comment: @Mr Heelis Could you explain your first comment in more detail? Preferably with code

Comment: @Mr Heelis The use of the lock statement contradicts the use of multiple threads because the threads still work sequentially.

Comment: @Kaskorian not necessarily ~(remember I told you it was *slow*) you see multiple threads are never truly parallel they always share *some* resources (even if it's just DISK<-->RAM) - using `lock` `wait` technique all you're doing is adding ONE extra aspect of competition for pooled shared resources. You'll be surprised to find it does actually work. (why else do it? a) cos it's easier to code b) remove all resource collision error and c) avoids creating race conditions.) Having said that **I don't use `lock` `wait`** I use threads **a lot** and code them very carefully using `static await`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with logging what exception is raised in GetThumbnail method. Your code hides it and returns null. Change to `catch (Exception exc)`, write exception details in log or at least evaluate in debugger. That can give a hint.

Also I'm pretty sure your VideoFileReader instances are IDisposable, so you have to dispose them by invoking `reader.Close()`. Maybe previous instances were not disposed and you are trying to open same file multiple times.

*Update*: video frame has to be disposed as well. Probably you will need to do a copy of bitmap if it is referenced with reader and prevents disposion.

Comment: Only two different exceptions are thrown out. The System.AccessViolationException and the AForge.Video.VideoException, which will be thrown out if the VideoFileReader cannot open the file.

Comment: Both exceptions occur in the Open (string path) method

Comment: I'm pretty sure, that I'm not trying to open the same file multiple times. First of all because in the List elements I check if there are two elements with the same path and if there are two elements I delete one of them. Also, I check while adding if the List already contains an element with the path. Second of all, I dispose of every reader after reading out the frame by using the keyword using...

Comment: @Kaskorian The code shown in GetThumbnail() method doesn't dispose reader. Additionally, while it iterates to skip video frames it doesn't dispose result of `reader.ReadVideoFrame();` I would dispose it and maybe there is a way to jump to required video frame directly without reading all first frames. Finally, I'm not sure which errors are thrown if you are trying to get frames after video ends. What if you ask to get thumbnail for 100's frame, but video actually has only 50 frames.  If you can provide simple test project, I'll take a look.

Comment: The code shown in `GetThumbnail()` method is disposing reader. You can compare the using statement with a finally statement of try catch in which you call Dispose(). Also, I added `reader.ReadVideoFrame().Dispose()` to the for-loop. Furthermore, you cannot jump to the frame you want, because they have to be decoded (only the changes to the previous image are saved per frame) and if the Video does not have enough frames a `AForge.Video.VideoException` is thrown out so the methode will return `null`

Comment: Probably you are looking at another code that I am, because in your question code sample there are no using statements.